# Why one needs git gc

Tags: git

It's said that during git garbage collection one walks through graph of commits and mark them.

All unmarked commits will be deleted, which is called GC.

The question is how it comes there are unmarked commits? I cannot decide how such commits might exist ?

Comment: If you delete a branch, rebase, or amend, or anything that replaces/removes commits, the old commits and any changed files they introduced are just left on disk. These things will be handled by the garbage collection routine when it runs.

Comment: Create a branch, commit some changes and delete the branch. A branch is just a pointer to a commit (and its history).

Comment: it's also worth nothing that `git gc` affects git objects and compresses them. Taken from docs => `Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository` src: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc

Comment: Downvoters, remember that according to Torvalds `git` isn't a full version control program. A full program wouldn't need a manual `gc`. This is a perfecly valid question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's worth noting that you typically don't need to run `git gc` - git will run garbage collection automatically itself under certain conditions. `git gc` just forces it to happen immediately.

Commits in git are immutable, which means that any operation that appears to change a commit is actually just creating a new commit. For example, if you were to do:

```
$ git add my-file
$ git commit
$ git add another-file
$ git commit --amend
```

It appears as though that last commit was amended, but in reality just a new commit was created.

This means that the old commit is no longer referenced by anything. Potentially git could get rid of the old commit straight away, but it doesn't. This can be really handy when you make a terrible mistake, because you can get your old commit back.

Another common operation that appears to change commits, is a `rebase`. In reality all this is doing is creating new commits at some other point in the tree that apply the same changes, and leaving the old commits unreferenced.

Another way to end up with unreferenced commits (also called dangling commits) that can be garbage collected, is if commits are only referenced by a tag or a branch (for example a branch that has not been merged to master) and the tag or branch is deleted.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `git gc` collects unreferenced blobs (files), which occur when you `git add` some updated file, then realize that your work was incomplete and make more changes and re-add the same file. In general, the fact that `git gc` exists, and gets run automatically, means that each internal Git command is free to create temporary objects for *any* need, and then simply abandon them and let the janitor clean up later, as it were.

Comment: Thx for noting commits are immutable